# In google cloud find ephemeral ip address of VM, from within the VM terminal (ssh or telnet)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After logging into the GCP VM using ssh or telnet I want to find the external ephemeral IP of the VM. (ifconfig -a doesn't show this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An external public IP address is not bound to a VM's network interface. Instead the network interface received a private IP address.

Within the VPC is a One-to-One NAT. The public IP address is bound to the public  side of the NAT. This is why you cannot see the public IP address with `ifconfig`.

Google stores the public IP address in the instance's `metadata`.

Execute this command to get the public IP address:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance
/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
```

The IP address does not have a newline, so your command prompt will be appended to the IP address string.

You can also save the public IP address to an environment variable and then print it to the console.

```
export PUBLIC_IP=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip)
echo $PUBLIC_IP
```

[Storing and Retrieving Instance Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)